# OctoberCMS: How to call Storage::url() from Twig?

Tags: octobercms

In Laravel 5.5 I use the following function to call assets from either filesystem or from the cloud:

```
<link href="{{ Storage::url('assets/my.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I know I could use `<img src="{{ 'banner.jpg'|media }}" />`, but that forces me to use the media manager only. In Laravel I can switch between the local filesystem and the cloud by altering `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),` in `config/filesystems.php`, which is pretty convenient.

That's why my question is how I could use `Storage::url()` in twig with OctoberCMS?

Answer (score 1):

in twig all depends on theme so you can use `theme` filter

to include js files you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ 'assets/js/menu.js'|theme }}"></script>
```

it will take url from the current theme and then `assets/js/menu.js`
same for css

```
<link href="{{ 'assets/my.min.css'|theme  }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

further info : https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-theme

> And include js and css for components  you can use helpers https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#component-assets

```
// inside component
public function onRun()
{
    $this->addJs('/plugins/acme/blog/assets/javascript/blog-controls.js');
    $this->addCss('assets/css/hello.css');
}
```

same goes for plugins you can add then using this.

if any doubts please comment.